# AngularJS filter null key:value row from ngRepeat list - data stored in objects within array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have my data stored in an array of objects and it is being used to create a list on the page with `ngRepeat`. The problem is that some of the values within the object are null and I want to hide just their line but not the whole object. I tried using `ngHide` on the individual `<li>`'s but it doesn't collapse the row since its just hiding it and I don't really wanna reduce its height to zero through a function or additional css if I can just use the filter to do it automagically.

Despite my best efforts I cannot seem to write a custom filter that will hide the null rows and show the others. I once had it to the point of returning `false` for the value if null but then I deleted it to try something else and forgot how I had gotten there (ugh no local versioning).

Here is a fiddle from a previous question of mine but it has all the pieces I am trying to filter. http://jsfiddle.net/E2GB9/9/

Format of the data:

```
function TypeCtrl($scope) {

$scope.styles = [
    {name: 'Example 1', h1:'32px', h2:'24px', p:'12px', className:'example1'},
    {name: 'Example 2', h1:'', h2:'24px', p:'12px', className:'example2'},
    {name: 'Example 3', h1:'24px', h2:'', p:'12px', className:'example3'},
    {name: 'Example 4', h1:'32px', h2:'24px', p:'', className:'example4'}];
}
```

`ngRepeat` in the html:

```
<li ng-repeat="style in styles">
            <span>Name: {{style.name}}</span><br>
            <span>H1: {{style.h1}}</span><br>
            <span>H2: {{style.h2}}</span><br>
            <span>P: {{style.p}}</span><br>
            <button class="btn-small" type="submit" ng-click="$parent.appliedStyle=style.className">Apply {{style.name}}</button>
</li>
```

So, if `style.h1 == null` then I want to hide that row only; same for h2, p and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `ng-hide` does not collapse the row is the `<br>` that follows every `<span>` element. It would work, if you wrote instead:

```
<p ng-hide="!style.h1">H1: {{style.h1}}</p>
```

(and no `<br>`)

It can also be a `<div>` instead of a `<p>` (or any block element, or style the `<span>` as `display:block` to force a new line).

Comment: Of course after staring at it all day I would miss something as simple as those `<br>`'s or even considering block elements. I decided to just go back this route! Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

You Can use custom filter with ng-repeat.

```
function TypeCtrl($scope) {

$scope.styles = [
    {name: 'Example 1', h1:'32px', h2:'24px', p:'12px', className:'example1'},
    {name: 'Example 2', h1:'', h2:'24px', p:'12px', className:'example2'},
    {name: 'Example 3', h1:'24px', h2:'', p:'12px', className:'example3'},
    {name: 'Example 4', h1:'32px', h2:'24px', p:'', className:'example4'},
    {}];

$scope.checkNull = function(row)  {
    return (row.hasOwnProperty('name') || row.hasOwnProperty('h1')  
|| row.hasOwnProperty(' ')  || row.hasOwnProperty('p')  );
    }
}
```

In place of row.hasOwnProperty(), you can also use underscore and check on size of the object.

This will not show the last row since it is blank.

ng-Repeat in html

```
<ul class="unstyled">
        <li ng-repeat="style in styles | filter:search | filter:checkNull">
            <span>Name: {{style.name}}</span><br>
            <span>H1: {{style.h1}}</span><br>
            <span>H2: {{style.h2}}</span><br>
            <span>P: {{style.p}}</span><br>
            <button class="btn-small" type="submit" ng-click="$parent.appliedStyle=style.className">Apply {{style.name}}</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. I tried implementing it like you said and also with a couple alterations but it doesn't appear to do anything. It is just returning the span item and a blank value as usual.